# Берутся ли в кавычки названия клавиш на клавиатуре?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли брать в кавычки обозначение клавиш на клавиатуре? Пример:
Нажмите одновременно кнопки Fn и F8. (нужно ли их брать в кавычки)

Answer (score 4):

В дополнение к ответу Сержа:

Если вы пишете на сайтах сети [Stack Exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#headers) (или других, поддерживающих разметку [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)), то обозначение клавиш можно заключать между `<kbd>` и `</kbd>`:

«Сырой» текст выглядит так:

```
Нажмите одновременно кнопки <kbd>Fn</kbd> и <kbd>F8</kbd>.
```

А отформатирован он будет так:

> Нажмите одновременно кнопки <kbd>Fn</kbd> и <kbd>F8</kbd>.

Кстати, в инструкциях для разных операционных систем принят разный формат записи. Пример тут: [Как использовать в тексте специальные символы: кавычки, тире, диакритические знаки?](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/43/177015)

Comment: Ник, а как можно научиться делать вот эти кнопки?

Comment: Нажмите на ссылку "править" и увидьте своими глазами как это сделано.

Comment: Ответ не к вопросу. Предлагаю снести на мету.

Comment: @behemothus: кончайте уже воевать.

Comment: Не я начинал. И давайте уже в чат со своим флудом.

Comment: А если по сути, то я не считаю корректным ваше навязывание здесь своих клавиш и оформительских правил. Четыре года жили без них - никто не страдал. На мете - нехай будет, если уж кому-то очень надо. А здесь спамом заниматься - уже перебор.

Comment: @behemothus: а я не считаю корректным, что вы мне запрещаете делать что-то, что в рамках правил Stack Exchange. Автору этого вопроса мой ответ оказался полезен. Пост на мете тоже был создан по запросу пользователя, а не по моей инициативе. Всё, что соответствует модели Stack Exchange я делал и буду делать дальше.

Comment: @Серж: я комментарии свои поудалял и вам это же предлагаю сделать )

Answer (score 3):

Названия латиницей в кавычки  не берутся.

Answer (score 0):

Тут нет однозначного мнения. Во всяком случае написание латиницей тут вряд ли может служить аргументом. *Клавиша "Пробел"*, например. Её тоже регулярно лепят без кавычек. Скорее может служит некоторым доводом, что на английском такие вещи закавычивать не принято. Зачем тогда делать это на русском? Я не о том, что мы должны следовать английским правилам, но каждый раз для отступления от них должна быть какая-то мотивация, а тут её просто очень сложно придумать.